# ASP.NET server error binding datatable to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Here is my exceedingly simple test dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Test" />
```

Here is my code behind:

> ```
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
>     dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(Int32)));
>     dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(String)));
>
>     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
>     dr[0] = 1;
>     dr[1] = "Test of text";
>     dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
>
>     Test.DataSource = "dt";
>     Test.DataValueField = "Value";
>     Test.DataTextField = "Text";
>     Test.DataBind();
> }
> ```

When I try to load the page I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'.
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You should reference DataSource this way:

```
Test.DataSource = dt;
```

to refer to DataTable object, not "dt" string.

Comment: Yes, I caught that not long after asking this question but by the time I came back to answer my own question you had beat me to it.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

`Dt` is Not a String it is `Variable` and Check For `AutoPostBack` So that `DropDownList` will Bind Only Once.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if(!Page.IsPostBack)

     {

    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(String)));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
    dr[0] = 1;
    dr[1] = "Test of text";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr); 

    Test.DataSource = dt;
    Test.DataValueField = "Value";
    Test.DataTextField = "Text";
    Test.DataBind();


     }


    }
```

Comment: This is just a test page so I didn't bother with checking for postback.

Comment: @9988ScooterGirl as per my experience good habit will make you code your best... :)